How to improve performance of Reportviewer ASP.NET Webforms using C#?
I have a ReportViewer that is extremely slow, it renders about 1000 rows in 13 minutes.
I searched a lot and find this solution to add
<trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full>

in web.config. It works fine, but my application use dynamic types so I cannot use it.
I have read solutions to resolve this problem in:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d89e2ce-3528-465f-9740-7e22aa7b7aae/slow-performance-with-dynamic-grouping-and-reportviewer-in-local-mode
and tried one, but it did not work, and I did not understand the rest.

This is a sample of code behind
aspx code.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

how fast is ur sql script running?

@Alander about 49 sec.
